# Aplicar CSS a um botão

Tags: html, css

Na empresa onde trabalho possuimos um sistema ERP, e estou passando algumas coisas para Web, porém no sistema existe um botão 'dentro' de um input que já é próprio da linguagem DataFlex

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para deixar isso parecido ou dando alusão de estar dentro do input para que os usuários não notem tantas diferenças ?

```html
<div class="col-lg-10"><!-- Inicio Input Descrição -->
    <label for="ex1">Descrição:</label><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#meuModal">...</button>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control descricao-input" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="20"  name="descri"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desta forma o `button` não está dentro do `input` mas da a sensação ao usuário.

```css
.grupo {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button, input, label {
  float:left;
  border:0;
}


.input_button {
  margin-left:3px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="grupo col-lg-10">
  <label for="ex1">
    Código:
  </label>
  <div class="input_button">
    <input type="text" id="ex1"/>
    <button onclick="console.log('clique no botão do input');">
      ...
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: muito bom, simples e sem precisar de libs externas +1

Comment: obrigado, atendeu minha necessidade

Answer (score 3):

Você está usando bootstrap correto ? precisa indicar um `.input-group`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="input com botão">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Botão</button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

Segue documentação relacionada: [Documentação](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/#button-addons)

Comment: obrigado, atendeu minha necessidade, no caso não tem como deixar idêntico mesmo, o mais perto possível seria isso né. @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade já tenho o bootstrap importado no projeto, só vou acrescentar mesmo as class

Comment: @VictorT. Ae a situação muda de figura, esse tipo de informação é totalmente relevante ser adicionado na pergunta. Agora não recomendo, pois o autor da outra pergunta deixou em "CSS puro", mas já que informou o uso disto, então a resposta do AnthraxisBR me parece a melhor +1

Comment: eu peguei as duas formas para utilizar, mas obrigado

Comment: Eu percebi que ele usava o bootstrap pelas classes dos elementos @VictorT. de uma olhada na documentação que eu mandei ali, tem como deixar bem parecido sim, expande um pouco o input, e joga uma margem pra esquerda no button, meio que mesclando o que eu respondi e o que o caique respondeu

Comment: obrigado, vou fazer isso, mas agora enfrento outro problema, na tela que eu estou replicando tem um checkbox do lado porém ao colocar o checkbox o botão fica para baixo do input

Comment: @VictorT. recomendo abrir outra pergunta pra essa dúvida.